# SwiftUI: withAnimation not working with App @State

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a `@State var opacity` at the  App level (i.e. not in a View). I would like to animate its changes. The changes do get applied (causing re-render), but it doesn't animate. I could only get animation to work when I moved that state var into the view.

Is there a way to get `withAnimation` to work with App state?

My reason for storing that state at the App level is, I also want to pass it to the `Settings` scene.

##### This does not work:

```swift
@main
struct MacosPlaygroundApp: App {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 1.0

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(opacity: opacity, onClick: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                    opacity -= 0.5
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let opacity: Double
    let onClick: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button("Press here") {
            onClick()
        }
        .padding()
        .opacity(opacity)
    }
}
```

##### This works:

The opacity-change animates for both the button in `ContentView` and the shape in `ChildView`.

```swift
@main
struct MacosPlaygroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press here") {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                    opacity -= 0.5
                }
            }
            ChildView(opacity: opacity)
        }
        .padding()
        .opacity(opacity)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let opacity: Double

    var body: some View {
        Color.pink
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .opacity(opacity)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: you should learn more about how swiftui works this is must watch video https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022
your first code is using a constant (let) and changed opacity outside will not change constant inside, try to research on Binding

Comment: @QuangHà "changed opacity outside will not change constant inside" - It does not need to "change the constant inside". Since `opacity` is a property of the `ContentView` struct, it's also a parameter to its default initializer. When the opacity of the App changes, it will pass a new value of this param to `ContentView`, causing it to re-render (the opacity does change after button click, just there is no animation).